# angular2 emitter not working with classes in separate files

Tags: angularjs, angular

The code given in this plunker works fine even when changed with subscribe in the beta version 50. But this does not work when the classes are put in separate files and exported.
How to have the classes in separate files and use broadcaster to reflect change in data. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/URXycFe3njtMKGmHrz9W?p=preview

```
broadcaster.subscribe(
  data=>{ generatedNumber => this.receivedNumber = generatedNumber}
);
```

Comment: Your are currently using an outdated Angular, 2.0.0-alpha.42, why not get the latest Angular 2 RC3?

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between components, you need to use a shared service containing an observable / subject. You can send an event that will be received by all components that subscribe to it.

You need to be careful to share the same instance. For this, specify the service provider into the main component of your application.

See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service